# IOS/Xcode/search/coredata: Can a Table View or Search Bar display from more than one entity when using Core Data?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, searchbar

Is there a way to have a search bar that searches more than one entity (i.e. table in Database Speak) and displays results?  For example, search for and display both authors and book titles with a certain string in them?

Note I would like to have this search bar on top of a table that only pulls from one entity.  The search should be more general in what it pulls than the specific table i.e. if you are looking at books pulled from a books entity (or table), could you search by both title and author in the search box above?

Comment: Do you want your search results to include books AND authors, or books where either the title or author name contains the search text?

Comment: I am not sure I really understand what you are asking: there is no direct link to the search text that the user enters and your core data fetch request - so you are free to implement multiple core data fetch requests in order to get results from multiple entities regardless of which entities are currently being displayed. But I suspect I am missing something in what you are asking - please elaborate.

Comment: pba..Books and authors.  The idea would be to have a universal search box that accessible from different screens that would yield multiple types of records.

Comment: Ali, the idea is to have a universal search box that searches whole database consisting of multiple tables or entities, i.e. books authors whether you are on books or authors screen. I guess you would use a separate search displaycontroller so you are freed from underlying FRC of view you are on.  However, would you then set up a queue of fetch requests with predicates that query different entities?  Or how would you go about querying multiple entities and chaining the  results?  I know how to do this in SQL through joins but not in IOS environment.

Comment: Each fetch/fetchedResultsController will get only one entity - so as per @AliBeadle, if you want to display several entities you will need several fetches/FRCs.  The difficult bit is presenting them in the tableview, particularly if you want them sorted in a way that intermingles the different entities.  The easiest option is to give each a different section in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple, really. Assuming every book has one author, use a search predicate for the book entity similar to the following:

```
NSPredicate(format: "author.name CONTAINS[cd] %@ || title CONTAINS[cd] %@", 
            searchTerm, searchTerm)
```